# Adding new attributes to DOM elements vs extending DOM elements prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is the difference between the two?

Say you have

```
var e = document.getElementById("myelement")
```

I see an example of something like this:

```
e.prototype.print = function(){
 if(this.nodeType==3)
   console.log(this.nodeText);
}
```

vs an adding new attributes to DOM elements example:

```
e.accessed = true;
```

where you're adding the accessed property to element.

It seems like both these examples are adding a new property/attribute to an element, just that the former adds the property to the prototype, so that all objects that inherit the prototype get the new property as well?

So if myelement was the only object inherited from it's prototype, would the following be equivalent to the first example I posted?

```
e.print=function(){
 if(this.nodeType==3)
   console.log(this.nodeText);
}
```

Comment: The example involving that `prototype` property was wrong, and would not work.

Comment: what if it was myelement.prototype.print?

Comment: DOM elements don't have a "prototype" property. Constructors have prototypes.

Comment: so if i wanted to add a field to all DOM elements of type div for example, how do i determine what the the constructor of these div elements would be?

Comment: In old versions of IE it was impossible. In modern browsers, there are constructors like `HTMLDivElement`, `HTMLSpanElement`, etc. Now, understand that there are downsides to messing with built-in prototypes. You're essentially dropping new things into the global namespace, and that can in some cases cause problems. Those problems are manageable, but you have to be aware of the realities.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`document.registerElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) . See [Custom Elements](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) , [Introduction to Custom Elements](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-custom-elements/)

```js
var proto = Object.create(HTMLDivElement.prototype);

proto.print = function() {
  console.log(this.nodeName, this.textContent);
  return this
}

document.registerElement("x-component", {
  extends: "div",
  prototype: proto
});

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if ("print" in divs[i]) {
    console.log(divs[i].print())
  }
}

document.registerElement("x-foo", {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLParagraphElement.prototype, {
    print: {
      get: function() {
        console.log(this.nodeName, this.textContent)
        return this;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
    //,
    // specify more members for your prototype.
  }),
  extends: "p"
});

var foo = document.createElement("p", "x-foo");
foo.innerHTML = 123;
document.body.appendChild(foo);
console.log(foo.print);
```

```html
<div is="x-component">abc</div>
<div>def</div>
```